# Android proguard, mapping.txt not working so well

Tags: android

I am using the `retrace.bat` file to check some stack traces from clients.

The problem is that the output does not really look like they did before, there are no line numbers and there is the word `void` appended to class names and `(Unknown Source)` where line numbers should be.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your **proguard conf** file

> -renamesourcefileattribute ProGuard
>   -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

[Source](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/retrace/examples.html)